# [NestJS]- Referring .env variables returning 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-config

I have been developing a rest API using NestJS with typescript. I have followed nestjs documentation on configuration and tried all sorts of tricks to inject env vars from `.env.${NODE_ENV}` files. But each time i am hit with `undefined` as the result. I have exhausted all ideas. Now I am looking towards the community for help. Please help me to identify where am i making a mistake.

*tsconfig.ts*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

*config.ts*

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import path = require('path');

const envpath = path.join(__dirname, 'envs', `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)
Logger.log(`using profile: ${process.env.NODE_ENV} & config path ${envpath}`);
config({ path: envpath });

const APPCONFIG = {
  ENABLE_CORS: process.env.ENABLE_CORS === 'true',
  SWAGGER_SCHEME: (process.env.SWAGGER_SCHEME as 'http' | 'https') || 'https',
  APP_VERSION: process.env.APP_VERSION,
  DEPENDENT_SERVICE_BASE_URL: process.env.DEPENDENT_SERVICE_BASE_URL,
};

export { APPCONFIG };
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { Logger, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthModule } from './abcd/authentication/auth.module';
import { HealthModule } from './health-api/health.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import path = require('path');

const envpath = path.join(__dirname, 'envs', `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)
Logger.log(`using path for configService : ${envpath}`);

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true, envFilePath: `${envpath}` }),
    AuthModule,
    HealthModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*auth.module.ts*

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
  exports: [AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

*auth.service.ts*

```
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService)

async timestamp(timestampDto: TimestampDto, timeStampUrl: string, authorization: string): Promise<any> {
    try {

      const token = this.extractBearerToken(authorization);
      this.logger.log(token);

      const downstreamAPIUrl = this.ConfigService.get(TIMESTAMP_URL);
      console.log('API URL: ' +downstreamAPIUrl);   #returning undefined

      const headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      };

      this.logger.log(timestampDto.payload);
      this.logger.log(timestampDto.publicCert);

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('payload', timestampDto.payload);
      formData.append('publicCert', timestampDto.publicCert);

      headers['timestampUrl'] = timeStampUrl;

      const response = await axios.post(downstreamAPIUrl, formData, { headers });

      return response.data;
    } ...
```

I have `.env.{NODE_ENV}` files in envs folder. the below is my project structure.

this is my directory structure...

```
├───dependencies
│   └───interface
├───abcd
│   └───authentication
│       └───dto
│           └───interface
├───envs
├───exceptions
│   ├───filters
│   └───persistors
├───health-api
│   └───interface
├───launchdarklyConfig
│   └───__mocks__
├───logger
```

this is inside `src/production/abcd/app` path.

*My `.env.${NODE_ENV}` file contains*

```
NODE_ENV=prod
TIMESTAMP_URL=https://abcde.com/api/timestamp
```

I have also tried not to use `dotenv` as `@nestjs/config` is wrapper around `dotenv` package. As per their documentation, `ConfigModule` and `ConfigService` must be leveraged to fetch the values.

My regards to everyone in advance.

Comment: `envPath` in `ConfigModule.forRoot`? You should use `envFilePath`, https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-env-file-path

Comment: @TalRofe Yes, it is envFilePath in my actual code. It is a typo in question.

Comment: Your code seems fine. If you just `console.log(process.env. TIMESTAMP_URL)`, do you see the value?

Comment: @TalRofe- I am getting undefined for even process.env.TIMESTAMP_URL

Comment: could you confirm this path is right from the log? `const envpath = path.join(__dirname, 'envs', `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)`

Comment: @TalRofe - yes, i am able to print the path pointing towards a directory where env files are kept.

Comment: so `process.env.NODE_ENV` does have the correct value?

Comment: @TalRofe- yes this is printing, as in my package.json's start:prod script, i have mentioned export NODE_ENV=${env_name} dist/*.js. This is why it is able to pick up the env name at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I created this minimal reproduce which works for me. You might want to compare your code to mine, it seems quite identical though (assuming you have typos in your code). Note that I just used `nest new .` to create this project from 0. Then just added the `ConfigModule` to the code.

**`package.json` file**:

```json
{
  "name": "playground-nest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.1.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.42.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  }
}
```

**`tsconfig.json file`**:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

**Some dummy environment variable file, `.yazif.env`**:

```
TIMESTAMP_URL=https://abcde.com/api/timestamp
```

**`main.ts` file**:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

**`app.module.ts` file**:

```
import path from 'node:path';

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

const envFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(__dirname), '.yazif.env');

console.log(envFilePath);

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true, envFilePath})],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**`app.service.ts` file**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

  getHello(): string {
    console.log(this.configService.get('TIMESTAMP_URL'));

    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

**`app.controller.ts` file**:

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

**Then**, after doing on terminal `curl http://localhost:3000` I can see on the terminal log the environment variable indeed set: `https://abcde.com/api/timestamp`

Comment: @TalRofe- I had to explicitly run export NODE_ENV=${env_name} from cmd before yarn build & yarn:start-prod. Then it has worked. This export was mentioned in package.json's build line script section. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @CK5 curious to know how did it help because you said your envFilePath is well defined before this fix